# Retrofit Library is Not importing After Create new project in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit

I create new project and Wants to Use `Retrofit` library in my Project.

I implemented this library for `Gson` and `Retrofit` but still I can't import it to my Project.

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.8'

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.2'
```

[Error to add Retrofit Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC7uc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here there is something to check weather it's all set or not.

1 - First implement the library in `builde.gradle` like below.

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.8'

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.2'
```

2 - Add this properties to your `gradle.properties`

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.nonTransitiveRClass=true
```

3 - Then Add Google() and mavenCentral in your `settings.gradle` like Below

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

4 - check compileOptions in your build-gradle file

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

**After all this steps you can import your retrofit and gson library.**

Comment: Thanks After Checking step-2 and step-3 it will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you sync your project with the gradle files? If not, the IDE (I suppose you use Android Studio?) will not be able to recognize/import the required library.

Check out the [Android Studio documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build#sync-files) to learn how to do this.